# Require locate wrong folder location of jquery-storageapi

Tags: magento2, requirejs

[image]

I have enabled developer mode. And I cannot find any version folders under static.
I have tried to clean the cache but it didn't work.

Anyone can help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: remove `pub/static` folder and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:delpoy`.

Comment: try to deploy static content by setup:static-content:deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally comment out the line of code:

```
 <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config"/>
```

in default.xml for designing page layout 
,which caused the issue, after I un-comment it, problem solved.

Thanks!